# keyDown doesn't produce the same keys and codes across browsers, what are some solutions to this issue?

Tags: javascript, events, keypress, keyboard-events, keydown

**Objective:** Listen for key press events to catch printable characters.

**Problem:** `keyPress`, the perfect solution for this issue, is deprecated and not recommended anymore, and the alternative `keyDown` doesn't produce the same `key` and `code` values as `keyPress` for printable characters, and it's also inconsistent with it self across browsers.

**Reproduce:** If you wish to attempt reproducing the issue, use [this website](https://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html) different browsers and compare your results

**Example:** when pressing `;` on keyboard:

1. Chrome ❌

| Event | key | code | which | charCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| keyDown | . | 190 | 0 | 0 |
| keyPress | ; | 59 | 59 | 59 |
| keyUp | . | 190 | 0 | 0 |

2. Firefox ✅

| Event | key | code | which | charCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| keyDown | ; | 59 | 59 | 59 |
| keyPress | ; | 59 | 59 | 59 |
| keyUp | ; | 59 | 59 | 59 |

**Current Solution:** I'm using `keyDown` and allowing only `key` values that match a `RegEx` to be processed.

**Note:** I'm using a keyboard with 2 languages, but I don't think this is should interfere with anything, since `keyPress` works fine.

**Question:** How can I get `keyDown` to produce same correct `keyCode` values that `keyPress` produces across browsers? Or should I just use `keyPress` dispite it being not recommended anymore.

**EDIT:** You may want to check out [3.3. Key Code Values](https://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) of this clever and well detailed article about this problem to better understand this issue

Answer (score 0):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode):

> KeyboardEvent.keyCode
>
> Deprecated: This feature is no longer recommended.

and

> You should avoid using this if possible; it's been deprecated for some time. Instead, you should use KeyboardEvent.code,

```js
const kbd = document.querySelector('kbd');
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  kbd.innerText = e.code;
});
```

```html
<input>
<kbd></kbd>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out sir, I didn't knew that `keyCode` was also deprecated, but that said the problem still accrues even with the use of `code`.

`keydown` just doesn't print characters from certain keys as they should be printed.

Comment: I've not found anything about `code` to be inconsistent. Where are you finding inconsistencies?

Comment: Okay so, in keys that have sign characters in them (like: ; : / @ é '  () |...ect ) and the number keys on the top that have characters as well, those preform on Chrome as if you where pressing Shift to only print numbers.

If you scroll to 3.3 in this article you'll understand clearly what I mean: https://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

also thanks again for your time

Comment: From [KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code): "The KeyboardEvent.code property represents a physical key on the keyboard" and "To determine what character corresponds with the key event, use the KeyboardEvent.key property instead."

Comment: neither key, keyCode or code are different, they all produce the same problem, the only difference being them printing different representation of the key pressed.
key: printing the character
keyCode and code: printing the code of character